# How to find out the variable types in sql result set in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I wonder if there is way to know the types of results I retrieved from the database in java. Ultimately I want to be able to use appropriate get method for each column of the resultSet (or be able to convert getObject() to the proper type) without me knowing anything about the database/data explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You will need the `ResultSetMetadata`.  Call `getMetadata()` on the `ResultSest`, then call [`getColumnType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType%28int%29) on the metadata object.

The returned value is from [`java.sql.Types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html).

Comment: beat me to it.  the easy ones go fast.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer It happens to all of us (and to me a lot today too).

Answer (score 1):

> The number, types and properties of a ResultSet object's columns are provided by the ResulSetMetaData object returned by the ResultSet.getMetaData method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29). It contains the type of each column, among other things.